# Read from csv file and put to Mysql with different field type using python

Tags: python, mysql, file, csv

i have table field of "datetime", "integer", "double", "string (varchar)" type in Mysql, how can i convert from string (from csv file) to each type of Mysql field using python ? example of my csv file :

EURUSD;M5;2011.01.05 02:10:00;1.33193;1.33193;1.33112;1.33135;0;-1;0;0;1.33215

My python code is like this :

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection 
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","me","xxxxx","test" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method 
cursor = db.cursor()

inputFile = "source.csv"

with open(inputFile, 'r') as fr:
    data = fr.readlines()

    for line in data:
        words = line.strip().split(";")

        getpair = words[0]
        gettf = words[1]
        gettime = (datetime) words[2]
        getopen = (double) words[3]
        gethigh = (double) words[4]
        getlow  = (double) words[5]
        getclose = (double) words[6]
        getcUpdown = (int) words[7]
        getfractal = (int) words[8]
        getzzId = (int) words[9]
        getzzUpdown = (int) words[10]
        getzzEndPrc = (double) words[11]

        print(getpair,"=",gettf,"=",gettime,"=",getopen,"=",gethigh,"=",getlow,"=",getclose,"=",getcUpdown,"=",getfractal,"=",getzzId,"=",getzzUpdown,"=",getzzEndPrc)

    #  =====================================================================
    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
    sql = '''INSERT INTO `mytable` (pair,timeframe,time,open,close,high,low,updown,fractal,zzid,zzupdown,zzlength) \
         VALUES (getpair,gettf,gettime,getopen,getclose,gethigh,getlow,getcUpdown,getfractal,getzzId,getzzUpdown,getzzEndPrc)'''

    try:
       # Execute the SQL command
       cursor.execute(sql)
       # Commit your changes in the database
       db.commit()
    except:
       # Rollback in case there is any error
       db.rollback()

    # disconnect from server
    db.close()

fr.close()
```

Thanks
p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type conversion in Python is done by:

   ```
   int(words[7])
   ```

   not

   ```
   (int)words[7]
   ```
2. There is no `double` type in Python. Use `float` instead.
3. You can not convert directly to `datetime`. Use `datetime.strptime()` to parse the input string:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime
   gettime = datetime.strptime(words[2], '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
   ```

   You might not need to do this (conversion should be handled when using parameterised queries - see below), but you can convert that to a string format that MySQLDB supports. You can use `strftime()` for that:

   ```
   gettime = gettime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
   ```
4. The sql query string needs to substitute the the actual values. Your
   query is inserting the names of the variables, not the
   values. You can (and should) use a parameterised query like this:

   ```
   sql = 'INSERT INTO `mytable` (pair, timeframe, time, open, close, high, low, updown, fractal, zzid, zzupdown, zzlength) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
   cursor.execute(sql, (getpair, gettf, gettime, getopen, getclose, gethigh, getlow, getcUpdown, getfractal, getzzId, getzzUpdown, getzzEndPrc))
   ```
5. `cursor.execute(sql, ...)` needs to be moved into the body of the for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot mhawke. I can not vote up, so just do a comment here. Tq.

Comment: Another question, regarding point (5): 
About  "for" loop,  in php we can do it in {}, like :  
    for (i=0, i<10; i++) { xxxxxxxxxxxx }
how to do that in python ?

Comment: @user2919408 : no problem. You may not be able to upvote, but you can accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @user2919408: in general PHP uses `{}` to determine the scope of the for loop. Python, however, uses [_indentation_](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) to determine the scope. So, in your code, you would need to indent the lines for executing the SQL statement to be at the same level of indentation as the `print` statement. You could move the SQL statement "template" string outside of the loop because it will be the same on every iteration.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot mhawke. You are really great ..... And how can i "accept" the answer ? I can not find any icon / link ... You have given great answer to my question. Thanks